# Using a custom domain with Firebase OAuth authentication in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-identity

We have an iOS app that authenticates users using Firebase Authentication and an OAuth provider.  When the authentication web view opens, the app first accesses `*project*.firebaseapp.com` before redirecting to the relevant OAuth provider page (e.g. Microsoft login).

We would like to use a custom domain rather than the `firebaseapp.com` domain.  We have set up the required firebase hosting for the custom domain `login.ourappdomain.com` but it does not seem possible to provide the custom domain in a native app as you can in a web app.

[Google's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/show-custom-domain) shows how to set the `authDomain` option when configuring the Firebase app in a web app-

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  // By default, authDomain is '[YOUR_APP].firebaseapp.com'.
  // You may replace it with a custom domain.
  authDomain: '[YOUR_CUSTOM_DOMAIN]'
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

There does not seem to be an equivalent `authDomain` property on the Swift `FirebaseOptions` object.

Are custom domains not supported in native apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you were right there is no equivalent `authDomain` property on the [Swift](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firestore-codelab-extended-swift/blob/master/Pods/FirebaseCore/Firebase/Core/FIROptions.m)

Both native Firebase [Android](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/ac3276ce7d5f5181b1c419731495eb88a98537af/firebase-common/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/FirebaseOptions.java#L30)/IOS apps do not support the `authDomain`option at this time. And this is a known issue, There is a Feature Request for `authDomain` in the [Github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7553) but currently there is no information on the priorities of this Feature Requests.

If you are willing to file  feature request you can add your concern in that github thread or you can raise new feature requests [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features)